# Selecting relevant boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations

Consider we have a set of boundary conditions for solving a set of first order ODEs. Consider the set as a list

```
bcs={y[0]==s1,z[0]==s2};
```

Now I want to solve the differential eqn $\frac{dy}{dx}=x$ with the boundary condition $y(0)=s1$. If I write

```
DSolve[{y'[x]==x,bcs},y[x],x]
```

It is failing to recognize the appropriate boundary condition. How I can use the same list so that the `DSolve` can find the appropriate BC by its own?

I do not want to write explicitly `DSolve[{y'[x]==x,bcs[[1]]},y[x],x]`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom wrapper that will select only relevant boundary conditions. The following wrapper `fixBCs` works for your simple case, but will need further improvements if you want to take into account more complicated cases (such as PDEs or non-numeric BCs ...).

```
DSolve[fixBCs[{eqs__, bcs_}], funcs_, x_, opts___] ^:= 
 DSolve[{eqs, Cases[bcs, Evaluate[Alternatives @@ (Head /@ Flatten[{funcs}])][_] == 
   _]}, funcs, x, opts]

bcs = {y[0] == s1, z[0] == s2};
DSolve[{y'[x] == x, bcs} // fixBCs, y[x], x]
(* {{y[x] -> 1/2 (2 s1 + x^2)}} *)
```

Comment: How to do for non numeric Q like y[0]=c1 ?

Comment: @TanmoyPati, just remove `?NumericQ`.